# In Kibana Dev Tools, how to delete all the documents in an index without deleting the index?

Tags: kibana

I want to delete all the documents in the index without deleting the index.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
POST /index-name-000001/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Further information is provided in
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

If it's a very large index add `?conflicts=proceed` so it's run in the background.

```
POST my-index-000001/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do this - it's horribly inefficient. you are much better off deleting the index entirely and then recreating it

Comment: Yes , I noted that but it's for a performance test ,so I want to keep the index but not the data.